# countdown for loop in Python

Tags: python, range, counter, countdown

This is my script and I want it to print and subtract `1`:

`for eachNumber in range(counter, 0, -1):
            print(eachNumber)`

from `counter` for each loop it does. When I try to place it in the for loop I currently have it prints all full numbers until it reaches `counter` I want it to count down from `counter` for each `for video_id in ids:` does in the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Download video meta-info for a given video urls from input file.

Input files is in Firefox'es bookmarks export file
"""
import csv
import re
import sys
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from gdata.youtube.service import YouTubeService

# parse bookmarks.html
with open(sys.argv[1]) as bookmark_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(bookmark_file.read())

# extract youtube video urls
video_url_regex = re.compile('http://www.youtube.com/watch')
urls = [link['href'] for link in soup('a', href=video_url_regex)]

# extract video ids from the urls
ids = []
for video_url in urls:
    url = urlparse.urlparse(video_url)
    video_id = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query).get('v')
    if not video_id: continue # no video_id in the url
    ids.append(video_id[0])

# remove duplicates
ids = list(set(ids))

# print total number of video_ids
counter = len(ids)
print counter

# get some statistics for the videos
yt_service = YouTubeService()
yt_service.developer_key = 'AI39si4yOmI0GEhSTXH0nkiVDf6tQjCkqoys5BBYLKEr-PQxWJ0IlwnUJAcdxpocGLBBCapdYeMLIsB7KVC_OA8gYK0VKV726g'
#NOTE: you don't need to authenticate for readonly requests
yt_service.ssl = True #NOTE: it works for readonly requests
#yt_service.debug = True # show requests

writer = csv.writer(open(sys.argv[2], 'wb'))
for video_id in ids:
    try:
        entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=video_id)
        dir(entry.rating)
        ['FindExtensions', 'ToString', '_AddMembersToElementTree', '_BecomeChildElement', '_ConvertElementAttributeToMember', '_ConvertElementTreeToMember', '_HarvestElementTree', '_ToElementTree', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_attributes', '_children', '_namespace', '_tag', 'average', 'extension_attributes', 'extension_elements', 'max', 'min', 'num_raters', 'text']
        comments = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(video_id=video_id)
    except Exception, e:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Failed to retrieve entry video_id=%s: %s" %(
            video_id, e)
    else:
        title = entry.media.title.text
        print "Title:", title
        view_count = entry.statistics.view_count
        print "View count:", view_count
        favorites = entry.statistics.favorite_count
        print "Favorite Count:", favorites
        comments = comments.total_results.text
        print "Comment Count:", comments
        if entry.rating is None: # skip it
            average = 0
        else:
            average = entry.rating.average
        print "Average Rating:", average
        if entry.rating is None: # skip it
            num_raters = 0
        else:
            num_raters = entry.rating.num_raters
        print "Number of Raters:", num_raters
        author = entry.author[0].name.text
        print "Autor:", author
        published = entry.published.text
        print "Published on:", published
        tags = entry.media.keywords.text
        print "Tags:", tags
        print "#########################################################"
        writer.writerow((video_id, title, view_count, favorites, comments, average, num_raters, author, published, tags))
```

Comment: It's the for `video_id in ids:` I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you mean, but I think the problem is that you've nested one for loop in another, when you don't actually want to do this. Try adding this inside your `ids` loop:

```
print counter, "videos remaining"
counter -= 1
```

This just decreases the counter once per Id, rather than running over the full range for each one.